# Sierra trying to update uninstalled software

Tags: ms-office, software-update, notifications

I'm using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2 and recently installed Office 2016. Before that, I had Office 2011, which I uninstalled before installing Office 2016. However, the Managed Software Center is still trying to update Office 2011 and I can't get rid of the update notification that keeps popping up frequently.

Is there a way to eliminate the update notification for an already uninstalled software? I was simply ignoring the message for a while but it started to get very annoying.

[image]

Comment: Isn't Managed Software Center for 3rd-party applications only?  Is this Mac in a managed environment where an IT department controls what software is installed?

Comment: Yes, it is in a managed environment and we do have an IT department. However, they say that the problem should not occur because I already uninstalled the previous version of the Office. So they don't have a solution proposal.